# Using APACHE REWRITE To Force One Specific Page To Be HTTP (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server-side

I have tried using some rewrite to change my /welcome.php page to http. it is located in the root directory, but what I have done has seemingly forced all pages on my site to http instead of just the one. Here is what I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Force remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.w5unt.ga
RewriteRule (.*) http://w5unt.ga/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

As you can see I am also force removing WWW from all urls at the same time I am trying to force my one page (welcome.php) to be http. I believe the error is in this bit of code
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`
However I am not sure how to syntactically correct my issue, any advice?

Comment: Indeed `^(.*)$`  is a catchall expression, thus all pages are downgraded to http. Something like this should do the trick: `RewriteRule ^welcome\.php$  http://w5unt.ga/welcome.php `

Answer (score 1):

Try with below I've edited the part of your rule and made a check to exclude welcome.php.

```
RewriteEngine On

#Force remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.w5unt.ga
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/welcome.php
RewriteRule (.*) https://w5unt.ga/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your suggestion, I will be trying this out tonight, if it works I will mark your response as correct!

Comment: @Leath what is the issue, did you clear cache beforehand.